# how to rotate a sprite object in three.js?

Tags: three.js, rotation, sprite

I need to rotate a sprite object but it seems this is not feasible, if not, is there a way to achieve the rotation effect, maybe through the UV coordinates of the spriteMaterial, or a custom shader? what would be the best way to go?

Comment: Is `SpriteMaterial.rotation` what you are looking for? http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html

Answer (score 28):

The rotation of a `Sprite` is set by its *material's* `rotation` parameter. For example, like so:

```
var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff, 
    map: texture,
    rotation: Math.PI / 4
} );

var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( material );
```

three.js r.67

Comment: a quick note: if you want to animate the rotation parameter you can change `sprite.material.rotation`

Answer (score 3):

It took me forever, but turns out you need to rotate the sprite material and not the sprite itself. Like so:

```
var scale = 1;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // Rotate the sprite:
    sprite.material.rotation += 0.01;

    // Resize the sprite:
    scale += 0.01
    sprite.scale.set(scale, scale, 0);

    // Move the sprite:
    sprite.position.x += 0.01;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```